# Multiple row retrieval with their latest inserted value using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, first one is 'file_details':

```
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field         | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| file_name     | varchar(40) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| creation_date | date        | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+---------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and second one is 'logs':

```
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sl_no     | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| file_name | varchar(40)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status    | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

values in the tables are:

file_details:

```
+-----------+---------------+
| file_name | creation_date |
+-----------+---------------+
| a1        | 2020-01-09    |
| a2        | 2020-01-08    |
+-----------+---------------+
```

logs:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+
| sl_no | file_name | status  |
+-------+-----------+---------+
| 1     | a1        | created |
| 2     | a1        | step1   |
| 1     | a2        | created |
| 2     | a2        | step1   |
| 3     | a2        | step2   |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```

now I want to retrieve the following data:

```
+-----------+---------------+--------+
| file_name | creation_date | status |
+-----------+---------------+--------+
| a1        | 2020-01-09    | step1  |
| a2        | 2020-01-08    | step2  |
+-----------+---------------+--------+
```

using the below query:

```
select f.file_name,f.creation_date,
        l.status 
from file_details f 
    inner join logs l on f.file_name=l.file_name 
        and l.status=(select status 
                        from logs 
                        where sl_no=(
                                select max(convert(sl_no,unsigned)) 
                                from logs));
```

But the above query gives me the below output:

```
+-----------+---------------+--------+
| file_name | creation_date | status |
+-----------+---------------+--------+
| a2        | 2020-01-08    | step2  |
+-----------+---------------+--------+
```

which is not a required solution. So, please help me out.

Comment: I'm new to sql. so please help me out

Comment: What's wrong with the advice provided?

Comment: nothing. but I didn't get my answer :)

Comment: Well why not take the advice provided and see where that gets you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there is a couple things to discuss here, you mentioned in the comments that you are new to SQL, so I will provide some links to look at, first off being [normalization](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php), this is used to reduce data redundancy (which you have with your status descriptions).

Also what you are trying to do is essentially make the engine "guess" what status is the most up to date one, using the `MAX` like you have will only deal with alphabetical orders and as such is not scale-able for if you say want to add a status such as "completed", so what you would have to do is hard code the order in something like a `case` statement which gets really messy with multiple conditions.

And lastly here is a [tutorial site](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-select-statement-query-data.aspx) on `SELECT` query basics with links to other data manipulation commands.

---

So the answer I came up with, I made a status table to store the `description` and then in the log table I store the `status_id`, doing this addresses the normalization issue I mentioned earlier. Creating this table also allows me to assign the statuses a rank to order with, which is another issue I discussed earlier.

```
SELECT t.file_name, 
       t.creation_date, 
       s.description 
FROM   status_details s 
       JOIN (SELECT f.file_name, 
                    f.creation_date, 
                    MAX(s2.rank_no) rank_no 
             FROM   file_details f 
                    JOIN logs l 
                      ON l.file_name = f.file_name 
                    JOIN status_details s2 
                      ON s2.status_id = l.status_id 
             GROUP  BY f.file_name, 
                       f.creation_date) t 
         ON t.rank_no = s.rank_no
```

Now I don't want you so blindly copy this query without understanding what it is doing, so the general gist is that the inner select gets the file names and creation dates with the rank number of the status, note this only gets the status with the highest rank number, then the outer select takes the data already retrieved and joins back onto the status table to grab the status description from the rank number. Giving the output

```
file_name   creation_date   description
a1          2020-01-09      step1
a2          2020-01-08      step2
```

If you would like to see the query working I have created a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=177a358027e43fa639909bb887c6a3a7) for you to try.

---

These are the data scripts I used to create the environment:

```
create table file_details( file_name varchar(40), creation_date date)
create table logs (sl_no varchar(20), file_name varchar(40), status_id int)
create table status_details (status_id int, description varchar(100), rank_no int)

insert into file_details values ('a1', '2020-01-09')
insert into file_details values ('a2', '2020-01-08')

insert into status_details values (1, 'created', 1)
insert into status_details values (2, 'step1', 2)
insert into status_details values (3, 'step2', 3)

insert into logs values ('1', 'a1' , 1)
insert into logs values ('2', 'a1' , 2)
insert into logs values ('1', 'a2' , 1)
insert into logs values ('1', 'a2' , 2)
insert into logs values ('3', 'a2' , 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`max(convert(sl_no,unsigned)) from logs)` will return `3` in your example and therefore it only matches

```
+-------+-----------+---------+
| sl_no | file_name | status  |
+-------+-----------+---------+
| 3     | a2        | step2   |
+-------+-----------+---------+
```